# Symfony Many to Many relationship submit datas

Tags: php, database, many-to-many, submit, symfony-3.4

I have 2 entities in my application, list and contact. I have a bidirectional relationship many to many.

I want to create a list that contains multiple contacts, a contact belongs to one or more lists.

The problem is: the contact that i added is not related to the list.

Here is the code :

list.php

```
//...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entiy\Contact,inversedBy="lists")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="list_contact")
 */
  private $contacts;
 //...
```

contact.php

```
//...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\List",mappedBy="contacts")
 */
 private $lists;
 //...
```

ListController.php

```
public function editAction(Request $request, List $list)
{
    // edit form
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $lists = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:List')->findAll();
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($list);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\ListType', $list);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('list_custom', array('id' => $list->getId()));
    }

    // new contact
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->addList($list);
    $form = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\ContactType', $contact);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($contact);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('list_edit', array('id' => $contact->getId()));
    }

    //return
    return $this->render('@MyBundle/List/edit_list.html.twig', array(
        'list' => $list,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        'lists' => $lists,
        'contact' => $contact,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Help plzzzzzzz!